# How to submit a questionnaire to my app users?

Tags: android, mobile, google-forms

I have an app in the Google Play store and I'd like to submit a questionnaire to my paying and non-paying users. I made the questionnaire using Google forms which gives me a short URL to send to people.

How can I tell my app users about the questionnaire? I'd like to show the link inside my app but it should show just 1 time possibly with a "do not ask me again" option. Moreover, how to stop showing the link when the user actually completes the questionnaire?

If this isn't the right Stack Exchange website please vote to close and point me to the right one (if any)

Comment: "How can I tell my app users about the questionnaire?" -- build a communications channel into your app. For example, your app could get this message from your Web service. "I'd like to show the link inside my app but it should show just 1 time possibly with a "do not ask me again" option" -- use a dialog box or some other UI in your app. "how to stop showing the link when the user actually completes the questionnaire?" -- that may not be easy, as you may not have a good way to tie some in-app user identifier to the form submission.

Comment: You could use shared preferences for this maybe. Store the link and a Boolean value in there. And once the message was shown to the user, set the Boolean value to false and don't show the message again until it is true. Or you could store all the data online, and use some sort of api to check if the user has seen the message